# Zipar diretório com PHP

Tags: php, diretório, arquivo-zip

Eu tenho um código que compacta arquivo e diretório. O problema é que ele compacta os arquivos e diretórios que estão na raiz, mas os subdiretórios eles não são compactados, por exemplo
Tenho esses diretórios:

> pasta/, pasta/arquivo.php, pasta/outra/pasta2, arquivo1.php

ele somente compacta pasta/ e arquivo1.php ...

Ele deve compactar o **arquivo.php, outra/, pasta2/**

Código:

```
<?php

function Show_files($local){

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if($zip->open('compact.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) == TRUE){

    $open = opendir($local);

    while($folder = readdir($open)){

        if(is_dir($local.$folder) && $folder != '.' && $folder != '..'){

            echo $local.$folder.'<br>';

            $zip->addEmptyDir($folder);

            Show_files($local.$folder.'/');

        }elseif(is_file($local.$folder) && $folder != '.' && $folder != '..'){

            $zip->addFile($local.$folder, $folder);

                echo $local.$folder.'<br>';
        }
    }
}

}
    $raiz = str_replace("\\", "/", getcwd())."/";
    Show_files($raiz);

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que você está **reescrevendo** o arquivo porque é uma função recursiva, então a ***instância*** `$zip` é criada todas as vezes que passa pela chamada da função recursiva. Para dar certo crie fora a instância `$zip` e passe como parâmetro da função.

Exemplo com `function`:

```
<?php
    function Compact($zip, $cwd) {
        $open = opendir($cwd);
        while($folder = readdir($open))
        {
            if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..'){
                if (is_dir($cwd.'/'.$folder))
                {
                    $dir = str_replace('./', '',($cwd.'/'.$folder));
                    $zip->addEmptyDir($dir);
                    Compactar($zip, $dir);
                }
                elseif (is_file($cwd.'/'.$folder))
                {
                    $arq = str_replace('./', '',$cwd.'/'.$folder);                  
                    $zip->addFile($arq);                                        
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if ($zip->open("arquivoFAfa.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true){
        Compact($zip, ".");
    }
    $zip->close();
```

---

Exemplo com `class` extendendo `ZipArchive`

```
<?php
    class Zipper extends ZipArchive 
    {
        public function Compact($cwd) {
            $open = opendir($cwd);
            while($folder = readdir($open))
            {
                if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..')
                {
                    if (is_dir($cwd.'/'.$folder))
                    {
                        $dir = str_replace('./', '',($cwd.'/'.$folder));
                        $this->addEmptyDir($dir);
                        $this->Compact($dir);
                    } 
                    elseif (is_file($cwd.'/'.$folder))
                    {
                        $arq = str_replace('./', '',$cwd.'/'.$folder);                  
                        $this->addFile($arq);                   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $zip = new Zipper();
    if ($zip->open("arquivoFAClassAbc.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true){
        $zip->Compact(".");
    }
    $zip->close();
```

**Dica:** Utilize a segunda opção, porque não terá esse problema de instância, apesar que a primeira é só criar a instância fora como relatado no inicio da resposta.