# Downloads multiplos com PHP e mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou tentando realizar uma função em PHP que realize vários downloads do arquivo em PDF dentro de um laço de repetição. O problema é que baixa somente uma vez o arquivo independente do tamanho do array.

Segue código:

```
$testes = array('teste','teste2');

foreach ($testes as $teste) {

   $arquivoHtml = file_get_contents(__SYSTEM_URL__.'/templates/teste.html');

   $arquivoHtml = str_replace('%TESTE%', $teste, $arquivoHtml);

   $mpdf0 = new mPDF('', 'A4', 0, 'Tahoma', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'P');

   $mpdf0 -> WriteHTML(utf8_encode($arquivoHtml));
   $mpdf0 -> Output("{$teste}.pdf", 'D');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente, esse código só vai ser executado um única vez, porque, o padrão é uma requisição por vez e no comando do [mpdf->Output](https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf) tem a saída de um download.

Para fazer algo parecido precisa gerar os `PDF`, compacta-los e depois fazer o download desses `PDF`, um exemplo seria a geração de um arquivo `Zip` e ai no final da geração desses `PDF` faria o download de uma só vez, para que esse código funcione tem que ser criado um pasta `temp` na execução desse `script`.

***Código***

<sub>***Observação:*** *o código atual teve alterações para esse principalmente na geração com o* ***template***, *e caminhos, fique atento a essas modificações e outra coisa.*</sub>

```
<?php

require('vendor/autoload.php');

// Criando PDF temporário
$testes = array('teste1', 'teste2');
$arquivoHtml = file_get_contents('templates/teste.html');
foreach ($testes as $teste) 
{    
    $arquivoNew = str_replace('%TESTE%', $teste, $arquivoHtml);
    $mpdf0 = new mPDF('', 'A4', 0, 'Tahoma', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'P');
    $mpdf0->WriteHTML(utf8_encode($arquivoNew));
    $mpdf0->Output("temp/{$teste}.pdf", 'F');    
}


// Criando Zip Temporário
$cwd = "temp/";
$nameZip = "arquivos_".(uniqid()).".zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($nameZip, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true) 
{
    $open = opendir($cwd);
    while ($folder = readdir($open)) {
        if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..') {
            $arq = str_replace('./', '', $cwd . '/' . $folder);
            $zip->addFile($arq);            
        }
    }
}
$zip->close();

// Removendo PDF Temporários
$open = opendir($cwd);
while ($folder = readdir($open)) 
{
    if ($folder != '.' && $folder != '..') 
    {        
        unlink($cwd . '/' .$folder);        
    }
}
// Download ZipFile PDF
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nameZip.'"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($aquivoNome));
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: 0');
readfile($nameZip);

// Removendo Zip Temporário
unlink($nameZip);
```

***Referencias***

- [mpdf/mpdf](https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf)
- [Zipar diretório com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23976/zipar-diret%C3%B3rio-com-php)

Comment: Vou tentar implementar e logo respondo

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

É por causa desta linha:

```
$arquivoHtml = str_replace('%TESTE%', $teste, $arquivoHtml);
```

você tem que substituir o nome aqui primeiro:

```
__SYSTEM_URL__.'/templates/teste.html'
```

E depois adicionar no file_get_contents

Ele baixa só um porque ele só pega o teste.html

Código:

```
$testes = array('teste','teste2');

foreach ($testes as $teste) {

   $arquivo = str_replace('%TESTE%', $teste, __SYSTEM_URL__.'/templates/teste.html');

   $arquivoHtml = file_get_contents($arquivo);

   $mpdf0 = new mPDF('', 'A4', 0, 'Tahoma', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'P');

   $mpdf0 -> WriteHTML(utf8_encode($arquivoHtml));
   $mpdf0 -> Output("{$teste}.pdf", 'D');
}
```

Comment: Ainda assim, ao entrar no laço só baixa uma unica vez o arquivo

Comment: Tenta deixar só 'teste' porque ele pode não esta reconhecendo por esta maiúsculo.

mas de qualquer forma tenta colocar um echo pra saber se o caminho esta correto.

$arquivo = str_replace('teste', $teste, __SYSTEM_URL__.'/templates/teste.html');